# How to I keep the text in this Slick.js element from going past it's container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I'm using [slick.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) to make slider. In order to keep my text div lined up with my media div, I've added the option :`variableWidth:true,` to the text div.
With this option, the media div and, text div grow and shrink with each other responsively. However, with the variable width option set to true - the text within starts to go outside of its container.

[jsfidlle with incorrect behavior](https://jsfiddle.net/5sck1b6u/)

[jsfiddle with correctish behavoir](https://jsfiddle.net/5sck1b6u/)

Correct look with `variablewidth` not set:[image]
I want the slider to look like it does above *but also, the text does not wrap neatly.*

Incorrect with `variablewidth` set to true:[image]
*Above: Text just runs off the page and, the next text slides do the same but they stretch further off the page  - making the blue box (containing div) look empty.*

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.text-slides').slick({
              variableWidth:true,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: false,
                fade: true,
                centerMode: true,
                asNavFor: '.slider-nav',

            });
            $('.slider-nav').slick({
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                asNavFor: '.text-slides',
                dots: true,
                centerMode: true,
                focusOnSelect: true,
                autoplay: true,
                mobileFirst:true
            });
        });
```

```css
.slider-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.slider-media {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 60%;
}

.slider-text {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    width: 40%;
}

.slider-media > .slick-slider {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.carousel-images > .slick-list {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.carousel-images > .slick-list > .slick-slide {
    width: 350px !important;
}

.carousel-images > .slick-prev {
    left: 10px;
}

.carousel-images > .slick-next {
    right: 10px;
}

.carousel-images > .slick-dots {
    bottom: -10px;
}

.carousel-images > .slick-dots > li button:before {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.carousel-text {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 20px;
    word-break: break-all;

}

.carousel-text .title {
    color: #bdc3c7;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.carousel-text .headline {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
                            <div class="slider-media">
                                <div class="carousel-images slider-nav">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="img/animals" alt="1">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="img/cats" alt="2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="img/nature" alt="3">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.block-media -->

                            <div id="text-slider" class="slider-text">
                                <div class="carousel-text text-slides">
                                    <div><span class="title">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error</span>

                                        <p class="headline">
                                            Sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
                                            totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
                                            veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div><span class="title"> Nemo enim ipsam </span>

                                        <p class="headline">
                                            Quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
                                            sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui
                                            ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div><span class="title">Non provident, similique sunt in culpa</span>

                                        <p class="headline">
                                            Officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem
                                            rerum facilis
                                            est et expedita distinctio.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Can anyone help me find a way to keep the text from overflowing **and** get it to wrap between words instead of in the middle of word?

Comment: Can you provide us a working solution either in a code snippet, JSFiddle, or a CodePen. Ideally with placeholder images, these might help http://placehold.it/

Comment: I'll make one now. Thanks.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz I'm trying to get the fiddle working now but, it's 404'ing on the external js scripts and css that I've added.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz here we go: https://jsfiddle.net/5sck1b6u/

Comment: I'm not 100%, but it seems to be an issue with slick.js. It's applying `style="opacity: 1; width: 2921px;"` (the width changes) to the div `.slick-track`. I'm a little unsure how to fix it, I did remove the style with jQuery which worked...briefly until it changed. It also caused some expected problems. You might be better taking it up as an issue on the repo https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues Unless someone here has a solution.

Comment: I did try `.slick-track{     width: 100% !important;     display: block;     position: relative; }` which fixed the text, but broke everything else. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the following:

In your css : 
    Remove  <strike>word-break: break-all;</strike>   written inside carousel-text class and instead write :

```
.carousel-text
{ 
 word-wrap:normal;
}
```

Also, don't forgot to mention the following :

```
.carousel-text
{
 width:40%; //Set according to your need.
}
.carousel-text .headline
{
 width:100%; //Set according to your need.
 display:inline-block; //restricts content from going out of parent div's size. 
}
```